# How do I display and calculate numbers from a database on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, database

I am new to designing apps and have a basic understand of Ob-C and how everything works.  What I would like to do is have two tabs, one is a home screen that displays numbers and percentages that are entered on the second tab.  The user will be able to store that information and refer back to it and update it.  What is the best way to complete that math from the database to the "home screen"?  Any tutorials, advice is great!

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not entirely clear on what it is you're trying to do.  What do you mean by "complete the math from the database to the 'homes screen'"?

Comment: Ok, let me see if I can clarify:

The app description:  2 tabs.  Tab 2 has input that gets stored to a database.  Tab one (the home screen) displays results from data(integers) that are entered on tab 2.  

By "math" (probably a dumb way to describe it anyway) I meant adding numbers that were entered and stored using tab 2 for display on tab 1 (home screen).  I really hope that helps.

Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is typically solved by using the [Model-View-Controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-view-controller) pattern. In this case, your "model" will be an object that stores the numbers and also does the computations with those numbers. Your "view" here will be the views in each tab -- the first tab visualizing the computations, the second tab visualizing the numbers. The "controller" here will be your existing `UIViewController` objects (or subclasses thereof) -- in the first tab, responding to changes in the data model and updating the (say) `UILabels` accordingly, in the second tab, changing the numbers in the data model when the user, for example, modifies the value on a `UISlider` or in a `UITextView`.

Create this data model object (which should just be a subclass of `NSObject`) in your application delegate, add it as a interface member/property in your view controllers, and pass it to both view controllers when the app starts up. Updating the data model is as simple as having the second view controller call methods and/or change properties in the data model related to various values it uses.

You complete the implementation of this pattern with the observation part. Here, you can either have your view controllers use [Key-Value Observing](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html) (might be simplest) to watch data members in the data model, or you can have the data model emit [`NSNotifications`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Notifications/Introduction/introNotifications.html) which your view controller would then register to receive (might be harder).