# iPhone SDK Programming - Working with a variable across 2 views

Tags: iphone, variables, nsstring

I have what I hope is a fairly simple question about using the value from a variable across 2 views.
I’m new to the iPhone SDK platform and the Model/View/Controller methodology.
I’ve got background in VB.Net, some Php, but mostly SQL, so this is new ground for me.

I’m building an app that has 3 views.
For simplicity’s sake, I’ll call them View1, View2, View3.

On View1 I have an NSString variable that I’ve declared in View1.h, and synthesized in View1.m.
I’ll call it String1.
View1.m uses a UITextField to ask the user for their name and then sets the value of String1 to that name (i.e. "Bill").

I would now like to use the value of String1 in View2.
I'm not doing anything other than displaying the value ("Bill"), in a UILabel object in View2.

Can someone tell me what the easiest way to accomplish that is?

Many thanks in advance….

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2224285/how-do-i-display-and-calculate-numbers-from-a-database-on-iphone/2231980#2231980) for how to build "Model" objects (in the MVC sense) that store data for use by multiple "Views".

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Shaggy Frog. I'll have to do my homework on how to implement the model object as simply as possible.

Answer (score 0):

You'd need a "model" part of MVC to keep that value in a variable and register observers in all views for that value so that views could respond to value changes and display it.