# How can I force a global variable to "update"?

Tags: ios, swift

I think this is a simple problem, so you might go straight to the question.

I have a global variable, switchStatusIndex, (does not belong to any class.):

```
import Foundation

//Default
var userIndex:[Int] = [0,1,2]

var userIndexForItem:[Int] = [Int]()

//Index to hold the switch status for all datatypes
var switchStatusIndex:[String] = [
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("switchA").description,
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("switchB").description,
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("switchC").description]
```

In **ViewControllerOne** I have a function:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    setupUserIndexForItem ()
    }

func setupUserIndexForItem () {
    userIndexForItem = [Int]()   //clears userIndexForItem

    for i in 0...userIndex.count-1{
        if switchStatusIndex[i] == "true"{
            userIndexForItem.append(userIndex[i])
        }
    }
}
```

Finally I have a **ViewControllerTwo** with UISwitches ex

```
@IBOutlet var switchA: UISwitch!

override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
}


override func layoutSubviews() {
    restoreSwitchesStates()
}


@IBAction func setStateSwitchA(sender: UISwitch) {
    var userdefault: NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

    if switchA.on == true {
        userdefault.setBool(switchA!.on, forKey: "switchA")

    }else if switchA.on == false {
        userdefault.setBool(switchA!.on, forKey: "switchA")
    }
    userdefault.synchronize()
}

func restoreSwitchesStates() {
    switchA!.on = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("switchA")
}
```

When I flip the switch to .on, it updates NSUserdefault to "true".
However, when I go back to ViewControllerOne, setupUserIndexForItem does not reflect this change. It is as switchStatusIndex does not update.
**Question**: How can I force a global variable to "update" ?

Comment: Your logic & understanding of global variable is incorrect. Google it  and see how they work - iOS global variable

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601341/iphone-global-variable

Comment: Use a segue from ViewControllerTwo to change the variable value in ViewControllerOne. Or set up a delegate method.

Comment: Why don't you use `NSUserDefaults` directly instead of wrapping it in another variable? That's not how it is intended to work. If you follow the documentation from Apple your values will always be the correct ones.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by many way.you can take switchStatusArray as global by putting in Appdelegate or you can use nsnotifiation or you can make delegate.

If use notification then first make method to intialize that array and use as a selector in notification method.

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(
self,
selector: "intializeSwitcharrayMethod:",
name:"intializeSwitcharray" object: nil)

     @objc func  intializeSwitcharrayMethod(notification: NSNotification){     
    //do stuff

         Self.intializeSwitcharraywithUserdefaults()
     }


  func intializeSwitcharraywithUserdefaults()
 { 
    // your code of array intialization
  }
```

You can call intializeSwitcharraywithUserdefaults() from viewdidload also.

Comment: Can you please show how to use NSNotification in this example?

Comment: Check edited answer and now on change in switch method post notification so intialization method call

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly your code, you're expecting the contents of the `switchStatusIndex` array to be updated every time you access that array from within the `viewWillAppear` method. But that's not going to happen because `switchStatusIndex` is set only once and never changed again. Perhaps what you intended was to define `switchStatusIndex` as a computed property or a property that is initialised by a closure, so that every time you access it, something happens (the array contents get updated with the values in `NSUserDefaults`).

Comment: exactly: every time you access it, the array contents get updated with the values in NSUserDefaults.  how do I do that?

Comment: I think the explanations and examples in the [_Properties_](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH14-ID254) section of _The Swift Programming Language_ guide are very clear, and a short read.